# Hugo: how can I test file path

Tags: templates, sitemap, hugo

In Hugo, I want to update a sitemap template so that it excludes a file if *either*  (a) the sitemap_exclude parameter is set to true, or (b) the file is below a certain directory.

Currently the test is:

```xml
{{ range .Data.Pages }}{{ if ne .Params.sitemap_exclude true }}
```

How would I also exclude files under the foobar directory?

For example, I tried:

```xml
  {{ range .Data.Pages }}{{ if ne .File.Dir en/foobar }}
```

(the directory is content/en/foobar)

But that gives me the error:

```
parse failed bad character U+002F '/'
```

(as does using a backslash - I'm on Windows so tried both)

P.

Answer (score 1):

https://gohugo.io/content-management/sections/#section-page-variables-and-methods

So a few things:

1. I would range ".Sections" If any section was set to not be part of the site map, skip it.
2. Else, index that section checking individual pages. If one of those pages represents or is a Section - Check 1. Else keep going.

I'm super psuedo coding here but:

```
{{ range .Sections }}
   {{ if .Params.exclude = true }}
   {{ else }}
      {{ range .Section.Pages }} 
      etc...
   {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

I have to check return types etc... etc... but that's the way I would go about doing this.

When I have a chance I'll check more of the code aspect and see what runs. Maybe this will help you though.

Answer (score 0):

A string should always be wrapped in quotes:

```
{{ if ne .File.Dir "en/foobar" }
```